# Why am I getting "undefined" with jquery.val()?

Tags: jquery, undefined

Goal: read in the current value of a set of text boxes. if the value is "None" replace the value with the value provided. Once a value is changed stop.

When I use span and .text() instead of a textbox and .val() everything works. However, the textboxes are part of a form.

Any idea why it would return as "undefined"?

(basically i'm making a list from user input)

html:

```
<input type="text" name="class1" value="None" ><br>
<input type="text" name="class2" value="None" ><br>
<input type="text" name="class3" value="None" ><br>
<input type="text" name="class4" value="None" ><br>
<input type="text" name="class5" value="None" ><br>
```

jquery:

```
function compareClass(a)
   {
      var input = a;
      for(x=1;x<6;x++)
      {
         var classText = $('.class'+x).val();
         if(classText == "None")
         {
            $('.class'+x).val(input);
            break;
         }
      }      
   }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are telling jQuery to look for elements with **class** `class[x]` but you are assigning **name** s.

You could change the `name` properties to `id` s:

```
<input type="text" id="class1" value="None" ><br>
<input type="text" id="class2" value="None" ><br>
<input type="text" id="class3" value="None" ><br>
<input type="text" id="class4" value="None" ><br>
<input type="text" id="class5" value="None" ><br>
```

and fetch by ID:

```
var classText = $('#class'+x).val(); // Note the #!
```

(obviously, "class" won't make any sense now as a name probably)

Alternatively, you could in fact use the `class` property but CSS classes can be be assigned to multiple elements, so it's not really suitable here.

Comment: :::facepalm::: that's what I get for looking at code for hours on end by myself. lol. thanks.

Comment: Use *String()* for the typecast: *var classText = $('#class'+String( x ) ).val();*

Answer (score 1):

Use selectors in jQuery to simplify your code. `[name^=Class]` means all inputs with a `name` attribute starting with `Class` (Quotes not required)

```
function compareClass(a)
{
  $('input [name^=Class]').each(function() {

     if ($(this).val() === 'None') $(this).val(a);

  });
}
```

Comment: You can use $('input[name="Class"]') as well